# getClassLoader not getting resources when run on Android Studio, but works on command line ./gradlew. Why?

Tags: java, android, classloader, android-resources, gradlew

When I compile my test using `./gradlew` command line

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    String currentDir = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("test.json").getPath();
    System.out.println("Current dir using System:" +currentDir);
}
```

It works, printing

```
Current dir using System:/Users/myname/base/project/module/build/resources/test/test.json
```

However, if I run through Android Studio, it will throw exception because it `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("test.json")` will return null (e.g. the resource is not copied over to the build folder).

Why this happen? How could I get a consistent behavior between Android Studio run and `./gradlew`?